# My function wont run the second condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, if-statement

My code wont run the second  condition if the value of `select is 1`
//Not pasted js code

```
function changeHref() {
    var select = 0;
    const link = document.querySelector("link");

    if (select === 0){
        link.href="css/styleOne.css";
        select = 1;
    } else if (select === 1) {
        link.href="css/styleTwo.css";
        select = 0;
    }
}
```

I tried to make the conditionals two strings being compared if they have same href values. But now I tried it as var variable that checks if the value is 1 or 0 but I am still not sure why it don't run. I did not try other attributes of other elements yet thaugh

Comment: Because you are always setting select to 0 at the start of your method. You need select to be a global variable instead of a local one. Pass it in as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are always setting select to 0 at the start of your method. You need select to be a global variable instead of a local one. Pass it in as an argument.

For example,

```
function changeHref(selected) {
    const link = document.querySelector("link");

    if (selected === 0){
        link.href="css/styleOne.css";
        selected = 1;
    } else if (selected === 1) {
        link.href="css/styleTwo.css";
        selected = 0;
    }

   return selected;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming there are only two values of `select` that is 0 and 1. In that case I will rather change the value of the `select` to boolean and assign the value of select outside the function.

In your case the `select` is initialised inside the function so it is always 0

```js
let select = true

function changeHref() {
  const link = document.querySelector("link");
  if (select) {
    link.href = "css/styleOne.css";
  } else {
    link.href = "css/styleTwo.css";
  }
  select = !select;
}
```